# How to detect if scroll action has happened in ui:scrollerWrapper

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, event, scrolling, uiscrollerwrapper

When scrolling action occurs for content inside ui:scrollerWrapper, I want to detect that and execute some javascript after that.

I have tried to add scroll event handler to the div that is inside ui:scrollerWrapper. But it doesn't listen to scroll event. I have tried to add listener to div that has "body" rendered inside it, but that doesn't work either.

Note 1 : "body" attribute contains dynamically created components.

Note 2 : I want to keep using ui:scrollerWrapper 'cause it's working nicely for me in iPad and desktop :)

Following is my code:

> Markup:

```
<ui:scrollerWrapper aura:id="scrollWrapper" class="scrollerSize">
    <div aura:id="scrollWrapperDiv" class="slds-card slds-p-around_small">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isLoading}">
            <c:card isLoading="{!v.isLoading}" />
        </aura:if>
        <div class="{!v.isLoading ? 'slds-hide' : 'slds-show'}" >
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_12-of-12">
                <div aura:id="contentDiv" class="{!v.areItemsEmpty ? ' slds-hide' : ''}">
                    {!v.body}
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:scrollerWrapper>
```

> Renderer:

```
afterRender : function( component, helper ) {

    this.superAfterRender();
    var scrollContent = component.find('scrollWrapperDiv').getElement();

    //Tried this, Doesn't listen to scroll:
    //var scrollContent = component.find('contentDiv').getElement();


    //Throws error. Understandable due to locker constraint.
    //var scrollContent = component.find('scrollWrapper').getElement(); 

    var mod = scrollContent.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
        component.set('v.scrollTopValue', scrollContent.scrollTop);
    });                
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code of `ui:scrollerWrapper` here:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/scrollerWrapper/scrollerWrapper.cmp

I can see that there is no external event or action that allows to capture a scrolling event.

Unfortunately `ui:scrollerWrapper` isn't extensible so you can't inherit from it. However the component isn't very complex so I suggest that you copy it and create your own that fires a custom `onScroll` event.
You can probably fire it from [this line in the helper](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/scrollerWrapper/scrollerWrapperHelper.js#L48).